# ajax safari6 cache issue

Tags: jquery, safari

I am using `httpRequest` object while sending request in mac safari 6. Request doesn't send because of cache issue. I tried to set request header `Cache-Control:no-cache` as defined below but it don't work. How could I resolve cache request issue when using `XMLHttpRequest` object.

```
http_request1 = get_xhttp_object();
http_request1.open('GET',url,false);
http_request.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");


function get_xhttp_object(){
    var http_request = false;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    { //all but IE
        http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        if (http_request.overrideMimeType)
        {
            http_request.overrideMimeType('text/xml');
        }
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject)
    { //IE
        try {
            http_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                http_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {}
        }
    }
    if (!http_request)
    {
        alert("http_request could not be established.");
        return false;
    }
    return http_request;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would be the following:

http_request1.open('GET',url + '?t=' + new Date().getTime(),false);

- Replace ? in the above line with & if the URL already contains parameters

Refer http://ajaxpatterns.org/XMLHttpRequest_Call#How_will_caching_be_controlled.3F